# How to INSERT data into a specific column without NULLs in the other columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have a table ("table1") with 3 columns called col1, col2 and col3 (each is VARCHAR) with 4 values as shown below:

```
col1   col2   col3
datA1  datB1  datC1
datA2
```

I need an ability to add a data at any time into any column NOT affecting on the other ones. The very popular code in the Internet is that (say, we need to add data only to the columns col2 and col3):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col2, col3)
VALUES ('datB2', 'datC2');
```

But it adds new rows, like below:

```
col1   col2   col3
datA1  datB1  datC1
datA2
NULL   datB2  datC2
```

What I really need is to fill the row starting with value "datA2" at the column "col1" with new values and get the table like below:

```
col1   col2   col3
datA1  datB1  datC1
datA2  datB2  datC2
```

The table has 3 columns and each column responses for a particular type of values (say: name, colour, size). What I need is just a possibility to add new values at any time in a particular column and have them without Null and new rows if it has a free cell before.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense unless your data is denormalized. What is the point of rows if you just keep stuffing values into each column like that?

Comment: It smells like bad database design..

Comment: The sense is that it is a storage for static values which will be added during the usage of the program.

Comment: Why do you think so, Oscar?

Comment: whats wrong with just having a `key` column, and a `value` column?

Comment: you also need to look at `update`

Comment: Modifying an existing row is an UPDATE not an INSERT.  Go vertical instead of horizontal.

Comment: Paul, the problem is, as described, that the SQL adds NEW row, instead of adding new data ONLY into the column.

Comment: Why can't you just have a single column for the value and populate just that one?  A database is *not* Excel.  If you wish to have it presented differently, that should be handled at the presentation layer, not within the data table design.

Comment: @ArseniiGorkin the root of the problem is poor design. You have a single row storing multiple values of the same thing. This is in violation of 1NF by having repeating columns. Make your life easier and put each value on a new row. Then you don't have to fight your table structures like this. If you design the ddl correctly, the dml is simple.

Comment: @ArseniiGorkin What DBMS are you using? Oracle? MySql? SQL-Server-2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (a chain of logical operations):

1) `CHECK` if there is a cell (in the target column) with values either `""` or `NULL`.

2) `IF` it has one of those then rewrite the FIRST one keeping the values of the other cells in this row at their places (assumably we use `UPDATE`))) ).

3) `ELSE` just add a new row with all `NULL`s in the other cell in the row.

If we want to add a few values into various columns simultaneously we may prepare our queries for all of those and then execute them simultaneously (sorry for tautology).

If we need to add a few values into the same column within one query we can prepare it, using loops (repeating paragraphs 1 and 2 (or, optionally, 3).

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE table1
SET col2 = dataB2, col3 = dataC2
WHERE col1 = dataA2;
```

This may serve your purpose.

Comment: May. But using an `UPDATE` to insert new data is a bit strange

Comment: As far as I understood the question, he meant to set col2 and col3 of row2 from NULL to some meaningful data. If he meant to insert new data, he need not mention about already created row2 :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `UPDATE` statement if you want to add data to an existing row. Like this for example:

```
UPDATE table1 SET
col2 = 'data5'
col3 = 'data6'
FROM table1
WHERE col1 = 'data4'
```

Also it does look like the root of your problem is poor database design, but this query is just to show you how to add data to an existing row.

Comment: Thanks.But, if I do not know the current value of the col1? Do I have to analyse the table every time to find out the values of the columns around to know where is the first empty cell of the required column is?

Comment: Yes @ArseniiGorkin. This is why we keep saying your table design is flawed. Fix the table and the query fixes itself.

Comment: @ArsenniGorkin If you know which column the new values will be going in then you can change the `WHERE` clause to check if the colums with the new values are null and if the other columns that will not be updated are not null. But then this change might update rows that you would not want it to update on, so @SeanLange's comment is correct. Fix the table design first then worry about the query.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answers! Guys, the design is not bad)) Why you think so? I need a table with a set of static data (values) which will NEVER be edited but only added new. I need them without empty (or nill) cells at the same colums between values (like '1', '2', '', '', '3'). I need them ordered. Your advices are underestimated and I understand that I COULD create diff. tables with only 1 column each, but I would like to use one omni table for all the values. Each column is the TYPE of the values which it contains.

Comment: If you could point much clear why you think that the design went wrong I would be highly grateful!

Comment: It depends on how the table is going to be useful for you. What is the purpose of having this "omni table" for all the values? If you do not want the columns to have null values then you can specify upon table design to have each columns not be null. So you will have to insert a value for each column when adding data to the table. Also please add a tag to your question on what DBMS you are using.

Comment: John, I was not clear, perhaps, describing my table (example) at the main listing. Thus I understand why you call my table "wrong design")). The table  has 3 columns and each column responses for a particular type of values (say: name, colour, size). What I need is just a possibility to add new values at any time in a particular column and have them without Null and new rows if it has a free cell before.

Comment: @ArseniiGorkin I will update my answer when I have time to write a query that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Given a table structure, with two data rows:

```
key         value
--------------------
team        accounts
manager     jeff
```

Each time you want to change a value, you need to check whether it is already there (for update), or not (for insert). So, to change the value of the `manager` property:

```
if exists(select * from keyValues where key = 'manager')
    update keyValues set value = 'mike' where key = 'manager'
else
    insert into keyValues ('manager', 'mike')
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the table
**CLIENT_MASTER**

**ClientNo   Name**
C00001       Ivan
C00002       Himanshu

Now you add a new column City

```
ALTER table CLIENT_MASTER  
ADD( City varchar(10));
```

Now if you want to add values in already existing rows you can use UPDATE command.
For example

```
UPDATE CLIENT_MASTER  
SET City='Delhi'  
WHERE ClientNo='C00001';
```

The updated table is
**ClientNo       Name               City**
C00001         Ivan                 Delhi
C00002         Himanshu             NULL

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col2, col3)
VALUES ('datB2', 'datC2')
WHERE col1 = datA2;
```

Comment: This is wrong. The `INSERT` syntax does not take a `WHERE` clause except when using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

Answer (score -3):

Use this, if value `null` then insert empty value.

```
$cal1=$cal1 ? "data5" : '';
$cal2=$cal2 ? "data6" : '';
INSERT INTO table1 (col2, col3)
VALUES ("'.$cal1.'", "'.$cal2.'");
```

Comment: What DBMS supports this? OP has not specified what DBMS they are using.